# how to configure ember-qunit in karma

Tags: ember.js, requirejs, karma-runner

I am using requirejs plugin of karma to load all libraries required by app. then included app files and test cases in files section of karma.conf.js. i am getting following error.

```
Uncaught Error: Script error for: isolated-container http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

i have included "ember-qunit/dist/amd/main" file using the following code in config file.

```
"shim": {
...
    "ember-qunit": {
    "exports": "ember-qunit"
    }
...
}
"paths":{
...
    "ember-qunit": "../lib/ember-qunit/dist/amd/main"
...
}
```

isolated-container.js file is located in amd/main folder. but failed to load.
ember-qunit/dist/amd/main.js is written in the following format.

```
define(
  ["ember","./isolated-container","./module-for","./module-for-component",
"./module-for-model","./test","./test-resolver","exports"],
function(__dependency1__, __dependency2__, __dependency3__, __dependency4__,
__dependency5__, __dependency6__, __dependency7__, __exports__) {
}
```

I am not very much familiar with requirejs. But as far i understood, main should be able load ./isolate-container.

Not sure why it is failing to load. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: adding "ember-qunit" under packages solved the issue.

    "packages": [{
        "name": "ember-qunit",
        "location": "../../../app/lib/ember-qunit/dist/amd"
    }],

Answer (score 0):

adding "ember-qunit" under packages solved the issue. raised an issue in github of ember-qunit(https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-qunit/issues/35) and got the answer

```
"packages": [{ "name": "ember-qunit", "location": "../../../app/lib/ember-qunit/dist/amd" }],
```